# Iterator for words returns characters

Tags: python, iterator

I have tried to build up my first iterator for words in a text:

```
def words(text):
 regex = re.compile(r"""(\w(?:[\w']*\w)?|\S)""", re.VERBOSE)
 for line in text:
         words = regex.findall(line)
         if words:
                 for word in words:
                         yield word
```

if I only use this line `words = regex.findall(line)` I retrieve a list with all words but if I use the function and do a NEXT() the it will return the text character by character.

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: What is `text`? A string? Then when you iterate `for line in text` it is iterating over individual characters...

Comment: Are you trying to split on whitespace?  Why not just use `text.split()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are passing a string to text because that is the only way it would result in all characters.  So, given that, I updated the code to accommodate a string (all I did was remove one of the loops):
    import re

```
import re

def words(text):
    regex = re.compile(r"""(\w(?:[\w']*\w)?|\S)""", re.VERBOSE)
    words = regex.findall(text)
    for word in words:
        yield word

print(list(words("I like to test strings")))
```

Comment: Would my code work if I put a "\n" at the end of my string?

Answer (score -1):

Is `text` a list of strings? If it's on string (even if containing new lines) it explains the result...